# Botão de upload de múltiplas imagens

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde, estou querendo adicionar mais um campo de fotos de acordo com o cod abaixo, esse botão tem que fazer upload de múltiplas imagens.. Quando coloco o c para rodar, não mostra nada na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052

Comment: Coloque o código aqui no site, fica mais fácil de obter ajuda ou quem quiser lhe ajudar vai ter que escrever todo o seu código na mão.